# Remove space from string except beginning of special character and end of digit into c#

Tags: c#, regex

I would like to replace following test using regex into c#

```
Input: P C $10000 F + T X (A)
Output: PC $10000 F+TX(A)
```

Means removing space except dollar amount.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Replace all matches of the following regex with an empty string:

```
(?<!-?\$\d+(\.\d{2})?) +(?!-?\$)
```

This will match one or more spaces that are not followed by a `$`, or preceeded by dollar amount.

For this to work your regex engine needs to support variable length lookbehinds.  This should not be an issue in C# but this regex may not work on online testing tools or in other languages.

Comment: This assumes that the dollar amount always starts with a `$` sign, **yet** assumes anything that ends in a digits, must have been a dollar amount. This doesn't sound right

Comment: @sehe The lookbehind also includes a `$` character before the digits, not sure I know what you mean.  If the lookahead needs to be more restrictive, you could use `(?!$\d+)`.

Comment: funny with nagative number "P C -$10000 F + T X (A)"

Comment: @user602291 Just edited so it should now work with negative numbers as well.

Comment: @F.J how i can remove space before and after special characters + plus, ( opening bracket, ) closing bracket.  shundn't need to remove space before and after $amount value. input: Max $250 (S)/$500 (F) + Gap + Anc  Output: Max $250 (S)/$500 (F)+Gap+Anc

Comment: @user602291 As far as I can tell, the current regex should already be matching the spaces that you want to remove in that example string.

Comment: @F.J i have another requirement which is similar to this but just need to remove space around special charachter +, ( and ) whithout remove space around $amount value. above expression will remove space after every charachter which doesn't fit into this requirement. so can you help please?

Comment: @user602291 Still not sure what the difference is between the requirements, can you give me an example string where the current regex doesn't match what you want?

Comment: current regex replacing "Max $250 (S)/$500 (F) + Gap + Anc" to "Max $250 (S)/$500 (F)+Gap+Anc", replacing "Primary Hospital" to "PrimaryHospital" , but i want replace "Max $250 (S)/$500 (F) + Gap + Anc" to "Max $250 (S)/$500 (F)+Gap+Anc" and "Primary Hospital" to "Primary Hospital", means only need to remove space from before and after following special charachters plus +, open bracket ( and closing bracket )

Comment: @user602291 Add the following to the end of the current regex: `(?=[+()]|(?<=[+()] ))`.

Comment: thanks thats work but one minor change this text should replace to "Max $250 (S)/$500 (F) + Gap + Anc" to "Max $250 (S)/$500(F)+Gap+Anc". Means special characther need to remove front space even if having $amount. Space before $amount is correct even in case of spacial charachter.

Comment: @F.J "Max $250 (S)/$500 (F)+ Gap+ Anc" to "Max $250(S)/$500(F)+Gap+Anc"

Comment: @F.J i have done using (?<!-?\$\d+(\.\d{2})) +(?!-?\$)(?=[+ ()]|(?<=[+()] ))

Answer (score 0):

```
using System;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

public static class Program
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string before = @"P C $10000 F + T X (A) ";
        string after = Regex.Replace(before, @"(?<a> -?\$?\s*-?\s*[\d.]+ )|(?<b>\s*.*?(\s?))", 
                    m => m.Groups["a"].Success? m.Value : m.Value.Trim());

        Console.WriteLine("before: '{0}', after: '{1}'", before, after);
    }
}
```

I took the liberty of accepting other amounts as well, e.g.

```
$ 10000
$ -2.30
```

Comment: When i tried negative number its removing space at end of number

Comment: @user602291 You probably had `-$10000`. I had only thought of `$-10000`. I fixed it now, supporting both styles